# Project level conception of modal and nonmodal forms

Tags: vb.net

I have project which consist of several forms and want to open it in certain modality rules which I can't achieve.

First, here is main form "Form1", then "Form11" and "Form111", "Form12" and "form121"

From main form "Form1" I can start only forms "Form11" and "Form12" like this:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form11.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Form12.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

In this situation, when "Form11" and "Form12" are showed I can easily exit application by pressing Button4 on "Form1" what will close all forms.

Now, here is another form, "Form111" which I open modally by clicking a button on "Form11"...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim f As New Form111
    f.ShowDialog(Me)
    f = Nothing
End Sub
```

And here I have some misunderstanding or misconception of my project.

When "Form111" is opened I like it to block "Form11" but not "Form1" where I would like to (say) open "Form2" or exit application where modal form "Form111" on nonmodal form "Form11" is opened.

Is it possible to achieve such functionality with described project configuration and how?

Comment: Project + Properties, change the Shutdown mode setting to "When last form closes".  Use Application.Exit() to force the app to exit.

Comment: Also as a sidenote, you should be doing f.dispose not f = nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the code for the button clicks in the first block may not be right.  If the forms are named `Form11` and `Form12` that is their class name.  They should be instanced as you do with `Form111`.

The *reason* the application closes is because that form (Me) is set as the startup form.  If/when that closes, the app ends.  You can change the app to exit when the last form closes in project properties.

As for your question, to have a dialog "block" `"Form11" but not "Form1"`, the answer is no.  Forms are either `Modal` (what you are calling "blocking") or `Modeless`.  You could tell Form111 to stay on top, but it would not be "blocking" any other form.

What you are trying to do suggests that the operations on these forms may not be as well organized or planned as they need to be.

Comment: I do my best to explain as better I can but as I can see not enough.. I am trying to organize project in logical and functional way. I would like to have Form1 which would be main Form from which I can close application in any moment.

Comment: I find solution! Form111 should be instanciated and called non modal (.Show(Me)). Inside _Load of Form111 I should do Me.Owner.Enabled = False and in _FormClosing Me.Owner.Enabled = True. That way Form11 is blocked when Form111 (which behaves like modal but it is not) is showed but in same time with Form1 I can close whole application or "listen" events from Form11 and/or Form111! ::HAPPY