# Non modal form that blocks its Owner

Tags: vb.net

I was trying to get forms configuration for my project that can suit my needs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19376819/project-level-conception-of-modal-and-nonmodal-forms) and didn't get to a solution. It seem's I find a solution and now I have to implement it application-wide.

Here I have main form and a few subforms (which have many subforms) and through the main form I should ALWAYS be able to close all opened forms, watch for universal keypresses, close application permanently and watch for critical events.

I find solution in this facts:

- From main form I open main subforms instantiated but non modally.
- From sub forms I open deeper subforms also instantiated and non modally.
  In all those subforms _Load event handler I disable calling form and in `_FormClosing` handler I enable it again. That way non modal forms act like modal forms in order to caller but not in order to main form which stays responsive all the time!

In forms that have to block its own caller (Owner) I added property "Blocking" so that my code looks like this:

```
If Not formIsOpened(frm_myFirstChild) Then
    Dim f As New frm_myFirstChild
    f.Blocking = True
    f.Show(Me)
    f = Nothing
End If
```

In the frm_myFirstChild I have property:

```
<Browsable(True), _
 DefaultValue(False)> _
Public Property Blocking() As Boolean
    Get
        Return _Blocking
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        _Blocking = value
    End Set
End Property
```

If boolean property "Blocking" is TRUE then under `_Load` this code has to be executed:

```
If Blocking And Me.Owner IsNot Nothing Then
   Me.Owner.Enabled = False
End If
```

In `_FormClosing` that:

```
If Blocking And Me.Owner IsNot Nothing Then
   Me.Owner.Enabled = True
   Me.Owner.Activate()
End If
```

All of that work as expected so I try to implement that for all forms and use when needed in a subclass "cls_transform":

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnFormClosing(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs)
    If Blocking And Me.Owner IsNot Nothing Then
        Me.Owner.Enabled = True
        Me.Owner.Activate()
    End If
    MyBase.OnFormClosing(e)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    If Blocking And Me.Owner IsNot Nothing Then
        Me.Owner.Enabled = False
    End If
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
End Sub
```

Here I have problem that subclass doesn't understand the property `Blocked` (not declared).

How do you get a Form's property `Blocked` to subclass so I can use those subclasses for all forms, and switch the property `Blocking` from the outside regarding functionality needs?

Comment: when you find yourself rewriting how Windows/.NET works, you should pause and consider that perhaps you are solving the wrong problem or solving the problem incorrectly.

Comment: You 're always free to offer good solution to problem if you agree that Windows/NET is not our master but just a tool to get what we want! This way I can get what I want due to various facts which makes my VS to be better and more complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me that "cls_transform" is actually a class derived from Form, the only way that OnFormClosing could work.  Which is okay, your "sub-forms" now need to derive from cls_transform instead of Form.  Do pick a better name.

Then simply add the Blocking property to that cls_transform class to solve your problem.

Do note that there's a bug in your OnFormClosing method.  It can be canceled and that will leave the form opened with its owner in the wrong state.  You need to write it like this instead:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnFormClosing(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnFormClosing(e)
    If Not e.Cancel And Blocking And Me.Owner IsNot Nothing Then
        Me.Owner.Enabled = True
        Me.Owner.Activate()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, cls_transform inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Form and most other form inherits from cls_transform. This was my class for transparent forms so I used it for new functionality to save number of files in project. In order to add Public Property Blocking to class I have to clear one in frm_myFirstChild what removes error. AND IT WORKS!! OnFormClosing fixed now too. Thank you very much Guru Hans!!